# How can this sum be maximized?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Suppose that $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7$ are distinct integers from $1$ to $7$. What is, then, the maximum value of the sum $$|a_1-a_2|+|a_2-a_3|+|a_3-a_4|+|a_4-a_5|+|a_5-a_6|+|a_6-a_7|+a_7$$?

Answer (score 0):

Given the first $7$ integers:

$$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$$

We want to first maximum the quantity $a_7$

Therefore, logically, let us set $a_7 = 7$.

Now, let's work backwards.

We need to maximum the sum $|a_7 - a_6|$

Therefore, we set $a_6 = 1$.

Similarly, we $a_5 = 6$ to maximum the quantity $|a_6 - a_5|$

Following this pattern, we get that $a_1 = 4$, $a_2 = 3$, $a_3 = 5$, $a_4 = 2$, $a_5 = 6$, $a_6 = 1$ and $a_7 = 7$.

Therefore, our maximum value is:

$$|a_1-a_2|+|a_2-a_3|+|a_3-a_4|+|a_4-a_5|+|a_5-a_6|+|a_6-a_7|+a_7$$
$$ = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28$$

Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Won't we get 28 if $a_1=4, a_2=3, a_3=5, a_4=2, a_5=6, a_6=1, a_7=7$?

Comment: The answer is false. Start from $a_7$ and you will end up with a different answer which sums up to $27$.

Comment: @Nicol I realize now that I have made a mistake. I forget to note the very last part of the question $a_7$. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Stef I realize that too.

Comment: What is the downvote for? I realized my mistake and made the necessary edits.

Comment: I suppose it was given to you for your old answer. I'll upvote you to compensate.

Comment: @Nicol thank you. Regardless for the downvote, the more important question is, do you understand how the answer was gotten? If so, then I'm glad to help.

Comment: I have some doubts about it. You start by maximizing $a_7$, and then procede to maximize the other terms with the digits that are left. But how do you prove that doing so will grant the maximum value of the expression?

Comment: @Nicol well, when maximizing an answer sum, we first look at each successive quantity in the entire expression. We need to proceed to maximize each quantity, therefore maximizing the entire expression. Some pitfalls exist to this process, but it's usually a guaranteed process that will always yield the maximum value.

Comment: When you say that some pitfalls exist, do you mean that it's not rigorously proven that the maximum is $28$?

Answer (score 0):

By using the triangle inequality $$|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$$

$\left|a_1-a_2\right|+|a_2-a_3|+|a_3-a_4|+...+|a_6-a_7|+a_7$

$\leq |a_1|+|a_2|+|a_2|+...+|a_7|+|a_7|$

$=a_1+2(a_2+a_3+a_4+...+a_7)$

$=2(a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_7)-a_1$

$=2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7)-a_1$

$\because$ it fully depends on $a_1$

Choose $a_1=1$,

$\therefore$Maximum$\, =2(28)-1=55$

Comment: You have an upper bound rather than a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

While the final answer posted above is true, the logic is flawed. Maximizing a sum is not equivalent to maximizing each term. I am sure one can give plenty of counter examples to that claim.

To prove the estimate 28 more rigorously I give the following hints:

First note that 
$a_k + |a_k-a_{k-1}| = a_{k-1} + b_k$ where 
$b_k = 0$ if $a_k < a_{k-1}$ and $b_k = 2 ( a_k - a_{k-1}) $ if $a_k > a_{k-1}$

This allows us to write the sum as

$ b_7 + b_6 + ... + b_2  + a_1 $

I believe you will have very little difficulty now in maximizing this sum. For one thing note that if forexample both $b_7$ and $b_6$ are nonzero then such a scenario will not be optimal as their sum will can always be increased by a reordering of sequence.

In short you see that the maximum is

2 ( 6 + 4 + 2) + 4 = 28